# Linking Error on GCC and Clang: What is '__tls_get_addr@@GLIBC_2.3'

Tags: c++, mongodb, compiler-errors, linker

I have trouble compiling the code on Ubuntu 12.04 and Ubuntu 14.04.
The code is rely on libcurl, libjsoncpp and legacy version of mongo-cxx-client. It works great on Mac OS. The code is bug free on Xcode.  However, it couldn't compile correctly on Ubuntu. I've open sourced my code here:
https://github.com/DengYiping/Shuoshuo_crawler/
When I use clang to compile:

```
scott@Harold:~/Apps/shuoshuo_crawler/shuoshuo_crawler/qqlogin$ make
clang -c -Wall -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ main.cpp -pthread
main.cpp:31:1: warning: unused label 'error_cleanup' [-Wunused-label]
error_cleanup:
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
clang -c -Wall -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ qqlogin.cpp -pthread
clang -c -Wall -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ fetcher.cpp -pthread
clang -v  -Wl,--start-group -lmongoclient -lcurl -lpthread -ljsoncpp -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lboost_filesystem -lboost_program_options \-lssl -lcrypto  main.o qqlogin.o fetcher.o -o qq_crawler
Ubuntu clang version 3.4-1ubuntu3 (tags/RELEASE_34/final) (based on LLVM 3.4)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8.4
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9.3
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.2.1
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8.4
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9.3
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.2.1
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9
 "/usr/bin/ld" -z relro --hash-style=gnu --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o qq_crawler /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/crtbegin.o -L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9 -L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../.. -L/lib -L/usr/lib --start-group -lmongoclient -lcurl -lpthread -ljsoncpp -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lboost_filesystem -lboost_program_options -lssl -lcrypto main.o qqlogin.o fetcher.o -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/crtend.o /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
/usr/bin/ld: //usr/local/lib/libmongoclient.a(logstream_builder.o): undefined reference to symbol '__tls_get_addr@@GLIBC_2.3'
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [qq_crawler] Error 1
```

This is definitely a linker error, but I have no way to troubleshoot it.

My Makefile when using clang:

```
CC=clang
CFLAGS=-c -Wall -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++
LDFLAGS= -v  -Wl,--start-group -lmongoclient -lcurl -lpthread -ljsoncpp -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lboost_filesystem -lboost_program_options \-lssl -lcrypto
EXECUTABLE=qq_crawler

all: qq_crawler

qq_crawler: main.o qqlogin.o fetcher.o
        $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) main.o qqlogin.o fetcher.o -o qq_crawler

main.o: main.cpp
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) main.cpp -pthread

fetcher.o: fetcher.cpp
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) fetcher.cpp -pthread

qqlogin.o: qqlogin.cpp
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) qqlogin.cpp -pthread
clean:
        rm *.o qq_crawler
```

Then I try to use g++ to compile, and this is my Makefile:

```
CC=g++-4.9
CFLAGS=-c -Wall -std=c++11
LDFLAGS= -v  -Wl,--start-group -lmongoclient -lcurl -lpthread -ljsoncpp -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lboost_filesystem -lboost_program_options \-lssl -lcrypto
EXECUTABLE=qq_crawler

all: qq_crawler

qq_crawler: main.o qqlogin.o fetcher.o
        $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) main.o qqlogin.o fetcher.o -o qq_crawler

main.o: main.cpp
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) main.cpp -pthread

fetcher.o: fetcher.cpp
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) fetcher.cpp -pthread

qqlogin.o: qqlogin.cpp
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) qqlogin.cpp -pthread
clean:
        rm *.o qq_crawler
```

And this is result. The result shows that condition_variables are not available.

```
g++-4.9 -c -Wall -std=c++11 main.cpp -pthread
In file included from fetcher.hpp:22:0,
                 from main.cpp:11:
threadtool.h:22:10: error: ‘condition_variable’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type
     std::condition_variable queue_cond;
          ^
threadtool.h: In member function ‘void threadtool::Threadsafe_queue<T>::push(T)’:
threadtool.h:38:7: error: ‘queue_cond’ was not declared in this scope
       queue_cond.notify_one();
       ^
threadtool.h: In member function ‘void threadtool::Threadsafe_queue<T>::wait_pop(T&)’:
threadtool.h:60:7: error: ‘queue_cond’ was not declared in this scope
       queue_cond.wait(locker,[this]{return !raw_queue.empty();});
       ^
threadtool.h: In member function ‘std::shared_ptr<_Tp1> threadtool::Threadsafe_queue<T>::wait_pop()’:
threadtool.h:68:7: error: ‘queue_cond’ was not declared in this scope
       queue_cond.wait(locker,[this]{return !raw_queue.empty();});
       ^
threadtool.h: At global scope:
threadtool.h:101:10: error: ‘condition_variable’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type
     std::condition_variable stack_cond;
          ^
threadtool.h: In member function ‘void threadtool::Threadsafe_stack<T>::push(T)’:
threadtool.h:116:7: error: ‘stack_cond’ was not declared in this scope
       stack_cond.notify_one();
       ^
threadtool.h: In member function ‘void threadtool::Threadsafe_stack<T>::wait_pop(T&)’:
threadtool.h:126:7: error: ‘stack_cond’ was not declared in this scope
       stack_cond.wait(locker,[this]{return !raw_stack.empty();});
       ^
threadtool.h: In member function ‘std::shared_ptr<_Tp1> threadtool::Threadsafe_stack<T>::wait_pop()’:
threadtool.h:134:7: error: ‘stack_cond’ was not declared in this scope
       stack_cond.wait(locker,[this]{return !raw_stack.empty();});
       ^
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, const char**)’:
main.cpp:31:1: warning: label ‘error_cleanup’ defined but not used [-Wunused-label]
 error_cleanup:
 ^
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Then I try to use clang to compile and gcc to link the compiled .o file.

```
g++-4.9 -v  -Wl,--start-group -lmongoclient -lcurl -lpthread -ljsoncpp -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lboost_filesystem -lboost_program_options \-lssl -lcrypto main.o qqlogin.o fetcher.o -o qq_crawler
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++-4.9
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.9.3-5ubuntu1~14.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.9/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.9 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.9 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.3 (Ubuntu 4.9.3-5ubuntu1~14.04) 
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../../lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'qq_crawler' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/collect2 -plugin /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/cc01qoam.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc --sysroot=/ --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu --as-needed -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -z relro -o qq_crawler /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/crtbegin.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../../lib -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../.. --start-group -lmongoclient -lcurl -lpthread -ljsoncpp -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lboost_filesystem -lboost_program_options -lssl -lcrypto main.o qqlogin.o fetcher.o -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
/usr/bin/ld: //usr/local/lib/libmongoclient.a(replica_set_monitor.o): undefined reference to symbol 'ceilf@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [qq_crawler] Error 1
```

I've open source my code here:
https://github.com/DengYiping/Shuoshuo_crawler/

Thank you so much for your support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are various things wrong with your makefiles, both with `CC = clang` and
`CC = g++-4.9`

The foremost error with `CC = clang` is that you are trying to build a C++ project
with a C compiler. `clang` is the LLVM C compiler. `clang++` is the LLVM C++
compiler. That is the cause of the undefined symbol references when you
compile with `clang`.

Though not the cause of any error here, convention dictates that makefiles
denote the C compiler as `CC` and the C++ compiler as `CXX`, so your
`CC` should become `CXX`.

Likewise the C compiler flags are denoted by `CFLAGS` and the C++ compiler flags
as `CXXFLAGS`, so your `CFLAGS` should become `CXXFLAGS`.

The linker option that requests POSIX threads is `-pthread`, not `-lpthread`.

Libraries required for linkage should be denoted by the variable `LIBS`, and
*other* linker options by `LDFLAGS`. You don't make this distinction and
include all your `-l<libname>` options in `LDFLAGS`. Then you wish to link
your executable with the recipe:

```
$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) main.o qqlogin.o fetcher.o -o qq_crawler
```

In the resulting commandline, this will make all of your libraries
appear before any of your object files, so the libraries will be
ignored and the linkage will fail with unresolved symbols. In the commandline
sequence of things to be linked, things that *need* symbol definitions
must appear before the things that *provide* the definitions. That is
why you need:

```
$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) main.o qqlogin.o fetcher.o -o qq_crawler $(LIBS)
```

The code you have published at https://github.com/DengYiping/Shuoshuo_crawler/
is evidently not up to date, because the makefile there is different from
either of those that you have posted here and in particular it refers
to an object file `downloader.o` for which there is no source file:
it ought to be `qqlogin.o`. However, if the code you have published
requires at least the same libraries as the code you are talking about here then 
there are two libraries required for linkage that are
not mentioned in your makefile: `libboost_regex` and `libboost_system`

There is a bug in your `clean` target:

```
clean:
    rm *.o qq_crawler
```

It should be:

```
clean:
    rm -f *.o qq_crawler
```

With out the `-f`, if `make clean` is invoked when the object files
or `qq_crawler` do not exist for any reason then `make clean`
will fail.

As you are linking `libjsoncpp` you need to have installed `libjsoncpp-dev`,
or else built and installed the library yourself. If you have installed
`libjsoncpp-dev` then your compilation on Ubuntu will require the include-search
option:

```
-I/usr/include/jsoncpp
```

Alternatively, you can replace `#include <json/json.h>` with `#include <jsoncpp/json/json.h>` in your code.

There are no more major defects in your makefile.

The `libmongo-client` distributed with Ubuntu <= 15.10 is too old for
your build. Therefore you need to build it yourself and either install it
under `/usr/local` or else provide a compiler option `-I/path/to/mongo/headers`
and a linker option `-L/path/to/mongo/libs`. From the linker
error messages you have posted, e.g.

```
/usr/bin/ld: //usr/local/lib/libmongoclient.a(logstream_builder.o): undefined reference to symbol '__tls_get_addr@@GLIBC_2.3'
```

I conclude that you have already discovered this and have installed the current
version or the one you need under `/usr/local/`, so you will not need
an `-I` or `-L` option for `libmongoclient`.

There is no need for you to compile with Clang rather than GCC. GCC is not
the cause of any problem.

Putting all this together, you can build the project published at https://github.com/DengYiping/Shuoshuo_crawler/ with
this makefile:

```
CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS=-c -Wall -std=c++11 -I/usr/include/jsoncpp
LDFLAGS=-pthread
LIBS= -lcurl -lstdc++ -lpthread -ljsoncpp -lmongoclient -lboost_thread -lboost_filesystem -lboost_program_options -lboost_regex -lboost_system

all: qq_crawler

qq_crawler: main.o qqlogin.o fetcher.o
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) main.o qqlogin.o fetcher.o -o qq_crawler $(LIBS)

main.o: main.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) main.cpp

fetcher.o: fetcher.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) fetcher.cpp

qqlogin.o: qqlogin.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) qqlogin.cpp
clean:
    rm -f *.o qq_crawler
```

It is not a praiseworthy makefile, but it will do.

Before you can do that, however, you need to fix the various compilation errors you
encountered in `threadtool.h` when building with `g++-4.9`. These are caused
by the fact that in `threadtool.h` you have not included the Standard header
in which [`std::condition_variable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) is declared;
so edit `threadtool.h` and add

```
#include <condition_variable>
```

after `#include <stack>`.

Now the project will build with the makefile above, assuming the required libraries
are appropriately installed.

Finally, as the build proceeds you will observe numerous occurrences of the
warning:

```
warning: ‘template<class> class std::auto_ptr’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
```

As it says, [`std::auto_ptr` is deprecated in C++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/auto_ptr). 
That is because `std::auto_ptr`
was a a fundamentally flawed attempt at a smart pointer. Deprecation means that
in future Standard libraries it will disappear. You should remove it from your
code and replace it with either [std::shared_pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)
or [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr),
or a combination of the two. Read the
documentation and decide which replacement is right for each of your `std::auto_ptr`s.

**Later**

> libmongoclient is actually compiled using clang with libc++ and c++11 on. It should work correctly. I still face some problem.

It won't work correctly. You need to download and build mongo-client from source (with GCC, default),
and install to `/usr/local`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install scons
$ git clone https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver.git
$ cd mongo-cxx-driver
$ scons CXXFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-variable
$ sudo scons install --prefix=/usr/local
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the code is correct under clang but erroneous under gcc since `condition_variable` is in thread or mutex header when compile with libc++ instead of libstdc++. It is a small difference between libc++ and libstdc++. Still struggle for glibc problem when using clang++. I am wondering if you successfully build this source?  I will post a up-to-date Makefile as soon as possible.  Looking forward to talk to you. Thank you so much.

Comment: libmongoclient is actually compiled using clang with libc++ and c++11 on. It should work correctly. I still face some problem.

Comment: @ScottDeng I have successfully built the project as downloaded yesterday with my makefile above. See updated answer.

Comment: `g++-4.9 -pthread main.o qqlogin.o fetcher.o -o qq_crawler -lcurl -lstdc++ -lpthread -ljsoncpp -lmongoclient -lboost_thread -lboost_filesystem -lboost_program_options -lboost_regex -lboost_system
fetcher.o: In function `fetch::Fetcher::parsed_json(std::string&)':
fetcher.cpp:(.text+0xb5d): undefined reference to `std::regex_token_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, `

Comment: Working right now. I'm just about to give up NoSQL, thank you so much.

Comment: @ScottDeng Good, and welcome to SO. If my answer solves your problem you should [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).
Then it no longer appears to be unanswered on SO; you get some reputation points and so do I.

Comment: @ScottDeng The above is an excellent answer to this question. I would like to point out that two common sources of error when working with the legacy mongodb C++ driver are mixing standard library versions among components (e.g. system boost uses libstdc++, libmongoclient is built against libc++), or mixing C++11 and C++03, since boost does not guarantee a stable ABI across language versions. It is important to ensure that your application, boost, and libmongoclient are all using the same standard library and language version.

Comment: @acm Yeah! Can't wait to see the new driver using C++11. It would be a lot better than using boost library.

Comment: @acm Thnak you for replying. Although this is not a problem of MongoDB driver, thank you so much. std::regex under libc++ is not trustworthy. I change the domain to boost::regex and it works great. Simple std problems. By the way, how's the new driver going?